# Different delays for in and out CSS transition in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to have two transitions enter and exit with different delays: in particular I'm trying to get the `height` transition of the `img` to start immediately after the `scrolled` variable is set to true and the opacity transition of the div to start after 300 milliseconds after that happens. On the contrary, I want the `height` transition to start after 300 milliseconds after the `scrolled` variable is set to false and the `opacity` transition to start immediately when that happens.

With the code below the transitions seem to work as intended when `scrolled` is set to false, but they start at the same time when it is set to true, what am I missing?

```
<div
  style={{
    height: "32px",
    opacity: scrolled ? 1 : 0,
    transition: "opacity .3s",
    transitionDelay: scrolled ? ".3s" : 0,
  }}
>
  <img
    src={logo}
    style={{
      height: scrolled ? "100%" : 0,
      transition: "height .3s",
      transitionDelay: scrolled ? 0 : ".3s",
    }}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: `transitionDelay` should be undefined or a string so try changing `0` to `"0s"` and see if it helps.

Comment: Im glad you could solve it

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Alvaro the problem was with `transitionDelay` being set to 0 instead of "0s", here's the fixed code.

```
<div
  style={{
    height: "32px",
    opacity: scrolled ? 1 : 0,
    transition: "opacity .3s",
    transitionDelay: scrolled ? ".3s" : "0s",
  }}
>
  <img
    src={logo}
    style={{
      height: scrolled ? "100%" : 0,
      transition: "height .3s",
      transitionDelay: scrolled ? "0s" : ".3s",
    }}
  />
</div>
```